# Are all linear transformations contained in the same subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

If a function is contained in a certain subspace, are all linear transformations of that function also in the same subspace? I believe taking the derivative of a function is a linear transformation, are all derivatives included in the same subspace as their original function?

Comment: All *linear combination* are contained in the same subspace.

Comment: Can you be specific about what you mean by "linear transformations of that function"? In general, linear transformations from a vector space of functions can map to anywhere, including not to functions at all (for example, the map that maps functions to their value at 0 is linear).

Comment: @MishaLavrov for example, if I have a differential homogenous function, I know that the solution set is a subspace, and I know that differentiating is a linear transformation. Does this mean that if a function is a solution then the derivative of that function is also a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true in general, and it is not true in the example.

In general, a linear transformation maps a vector space $V$ to a different vector space $W$; $V$ and $W$ do not have to be related in any way. Even if a linear transformation maps $V$ to itself (as in the case of taking derivatives) then a subspace of $V$ does not need to be preserved.

In particular, taking derivatives will almost never preserve subspaces of the vector space of functions, except in special cases. For example, the set of functions $f$ with $f(0)=0$ is a subspace. However, taking the derivative with respect to $x$ maps $f(x)=x$ to $f'(x)=1$; the first one is in the subspace, and the second is not.

Lots of solution sets to easy differential equations tend to be things like $\{A e^{2x} + B e^{3x} : A,B \in \mathbb R\}$, and these happen to be preserved by differentiation, which may mislead you. That's because of the particular form of such a solution, not a general property. There are plenty of differential equations whose solution sets don't behave like this.